# MySQL: many to many how to get all (related) categories & combine queries

Tags: mysql, join, many-to-many

The table:

```
id | category   (there is a index on id & category)
-----------
1  |  1
1  |  7
1  |  3

2  |  1
2  |  2
2  |  4

3  |  1
3  |  6
3  |  3

SELECT DISTINCT
    category
FROM 
    many_to_many e1     
WHERE id IN 
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        e1.id
    FROM 
        many_to_many e1           
    INNER JOIN
        many_to_many x1 
      ON e1.id=x1.id
    WHERE
        e1.category IN (3)
    )
```

I like to get retured: ** 6, 1, 7** (what I do get with the query above)
It seems to me this query is not gone preform well, because the sub query searches all the ID's and this list can be huge.

Also it doesn't matter how many but if the ID is related.
So for performance if there would be 100 id's checking once for each unique category to be populated would be enough.

Secondly I use an other query (the sub query )the get all id's who contain the category:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        e1.id
    FROM 
        many_to_many e1           
    INNER JOIN
        many_to_many x1 
      ON e1.id=x1.id
    WHERE
        e1.category IN (3)

 returns: 3 & 1
```

What would be the most efficient way to query the result I like. Is there an more efficient (better preforming) solution?
  Should I use one instead of two query's?

Comment: why do you want `1` twice? Is it OK to get just `3, 6, 1, 7`?

Comment: sort of typo I don't need it twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        x1.category
    FROM 
        many_to_many e1           
    INNER JOIN
        many_to_many x1 
      ON e1.id = x1.id
    WHERE
        e1.category = 3          --- IN (3) 
      AND
        x1.category <> 3         --- NOT IN (3)
```

You shouldl check the plan of the query with EXPLAIN. A compound index on `(category, id)` might be good for this query.

Comment: Although the answer of mathematical.coffee give the same performance results for now (small table) I think with a larger DB this solution is faster and a bit more elegant. thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT e2.category
FROM many_to_many e1, many_to_many e2
WHERE
    e1.category='3'
    AND e1.id=e2.id
```

This uses the table twice, getting all categories containing an ID which has category '3'. This also returns category '3', which you may exclude if you like.

Answer (score 1):

First your second query (all id's that contain category 3) doesn't require the join to `x1` (notice how you don't use it at all):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    e1.id
FROM 
    many_to_many e1           
WHERE
    e1.category IN (3)
```

Then your first query can be simplified:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    category
FROM 
    many_to_many e1     
WHERE id IN 
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        e1.id
    FROM 
        many_to_many e1           
    WHERE
        e1.category IN (3)
    )
```

### Solution

**However** instead of using a subquery you can just join, which is usually more efficient than a sub-query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e2.category 
FROM many_to_many e1 
LEFT JOIN many_to_many e2 ON e1.id=e2.id 
WHERE e1.category IN (3);
```

This joins `many_to_many` to itself on `id` which forms all combinations of categories for each `id`. In particular, there will be a row `(3,i)` for all other categories `i` that appear in the same `id`.

If you don't want 3 to be included, change the `LEFT JOIN` to:

```
LEFT JOIN many_to_may e2 ON e1.id=e2.id AND e1.category<>e2.category
```